# emgu cv Ip camera geovision gv-cb220

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, emgucv, ip-camera

I'm tring to use, in an applcation (face recognition) in c#, to get real tine stream from my IP Camera "geovision gv-cb220", but I don't have success. 
Camera work fine while using IE browser.
I have access to camera at 192.168.0.10, and there are user settings and password for access.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: more details !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: how can I connect to IP camera, from a C# application (usign EMGU Cv)? For example  private Capture capWebcam; capWebcam = new Capture("192.160.0.10");.....

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144527/how-to-get-video-from-ip-camera-using-emgucv and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934961/connect-to-ip-camera-using-emgu-cvs-capture-new-capture

Comment: I'm trying capWebcam = new Capture ("http://username:password@[192.168.0.10]") but I catch the exception : Unable to create capture from username:password@[192.168.0.10 –  user3415092 11 mins ago

Comment: are you sure of the password and the username, and post the exception message and the inner exception as well

Comment: exception message : "Unable to create capture from http://admin:admin@[192.168.0.10]"  user and password are correct

Comment: yes you said an exception is thrown !, what is the type of the exception and what is the message (google on howto get them if you dont know)

Comment: as I wrote "Unable to create capture from [link]http:// admin:admin@192.168.0.10"